# Using an expression $eq in an $cond mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to return "O" when the value of the field `size.value` is `true` and "N" when it's `false`. I am going for the `$cond` but so far it only return "O" because if I only put the path `$size.value` as a condition. Then the condition will be consider `true` if the field exist.

I tried to put an `$eq` on the value of `$size.value` but it's returning an error

```
db.getCollection('collectionA').aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             "Object":
               { $cond: { if: {"$size.value"{$eq:"true"}}, then: "O", else: "N" } },
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

Do we've any solution with this method or should I move and go with switch or any other method ?

Update : The value of the field `'$size.value'` is not a type boolean but a type String with 2 values possible `'true'` and `'false'`

So I am looking to check if the value of the field `'$size.value'` is a String equal to `'true'` or `'false'`

Comment: Please include an example of a document you are trying to query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below :

If you wanted to check value of field `size.value` is equal to `true` (this query would usually return 'N' on documents where `size.value` field doesn't exist or value of it doesn't match with `true`, Basically there is syntax error in your query) :

```
db.getCollection('yourCollectionName').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project:
            {
                'Object':
                    { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$size.value', true] }, 'O', 'N'] }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Else if you wanted to check field `size.value` exists, then this (As `$exist` doesn't work with `$cond` we need to do this) :

```
db.getCollection('yourCollectionName').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project:
            {
                'Object':
                    { $cond: [{ $ne: [{ $ifNull: ['$size.value', 'N'] }, 'N'] }, 'O', 'N'] }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I am in the first case. I want to check the value of '$size.value' and not his existence.
But I just realized that the value of '$size.value' is not a boolean but a string with two value 'true' and 'false' 
I will update the question

Comment: @BrunoSENELLART : then you just need to replace boolean true with “true” which would make it a string match on that field, rest everything should be the same..